# java.sql.SQLException: No data found 4

Tags: java

```
while (rs1.next() == true) 
{
    int rem=rs1.getInt("remaining"); 
    int thre=rs1.getInt("thre"); 

    if(rem==0)
    {
        String nname=rs1.getString("BNode");
        Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement();
        String sql2 = " update LBA set Status='Overload' where BNode='"+nname+"'";
        stmt2.executeUpdate(sql2);
        System.out.println("Node Status updated to Overload");
    }

    if(rem==thre)
    {
        String nname=rs1.getString("BNode");
        Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement();
        String sql2 = " update LBA set Status='Idle' where BNode='"+nname+"'";
        stmt2.executeUpdate(sql2);
        System.out.println("Node Status updated to Idle");
    }

    if(rem<thre)
    {
        String nname=rs1.getString("BNode");
        Statement stmt2 = con.createStatement();
        String sql2 = " update LBA set Status='Normal' where BNode='"+nname+"'";
        stmt2.executeUpdate(sql2);
        System.out.println("Node Status updated to Normal");
    }

}
```

I have 
Row 1 as Normal Status
Row 2 as Overload Status
Row 3 as Normal Status

When using MS Access, while trying to update the status,
It updates the first two rows as required,
but throws an exception in the 3rd row and doesn't update the status to Normal.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Looks like there is no record found. Have you tried to run the query on a console?

Comment: Yes, I tried running it on a console and this is the displayed output:-Running balancer A
Node Status updated to Normal
Node Status updated to Overload
java.sql.SQLException: No data found

Comment: Why are you getting BNode twice from Resultset?

Comment: Get BNODE only once from Resultset and store it in variable. Use that variable later.

Comment: Thank You. It worked :). Thanks a lot